# C++ Unlocking a std::mutex before calling std::unique_lock wait

Tags: c++, locking, race-condition, stdthread

I have a multithreaded application (using std::thread) with a manager (class Tree) that executes some piece of code on different subtrees (embedded struct SubTree) in parallel. The basic idea is that each instance of SubTree has a deque that store objects. If the deque is empty, the thread waits until a new element is inserted in the deque or the termination criteria is reached. One subtree can generate objects and push them in the deque of another subtree. For convenience, all my std::mutex, std::locks and std::variable_condition are stored in a struct called "locks".

The class Tree creates some threads that run the following method (first attempt) :

```
void Tree::launch(SubTree & st, Locks & locks )
{
/* some code */

std::lock_guard<std::mutex> deque_lock(locks.deque_mutex_[st.id_]) ; // lock the access to the deque of subtree st
if (st.deque_.empty())  // check that the deque is still empty
{
    // some threads are still running, wait for them to terminate

    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> wait_lock(locks.restart_mutex_[st.id_]) ;
    locks.restart_condition_[st.id_].wait(wait_lock) ;   
}

/* some code */
}
```

The problem is that "deque_lock" is still locked while the thread is waiting. Hence no object can be added in the deque of the current thread by a concurrent one.

So I turned the lock_guard into a unique_lock and managed the lock/unlock manually :

```
void launch(SubTree & st, Locks & locks )
{
/* some code */

std::unique_lock<std::mutex> deque_lock(locks.deque_mutex_[st.id_]) ; // lock the access to the deque of subtree st
if (st.deque_.empty())          // check that the deque is still empty
{
    deque_lock.unlock() ; // unlock the access to the deque to enable the other threads to add objects

    // DATA RACE : nothing must happen to the unprotected deque here !!!!!!

    // some threads are still running, wait for them to terminate

    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> wait_lock(locks.restart_mutex_[st.id_]) ;
    locks.restart_condition_[st.id_].wait(wait_lock) ;   
}

/* some code */
}
```

The problem now, is that there is a data race, and I would like to make sure that the "wait" instruction is performed directly after the "deque_lock.unlock()" one. Would anyone know a way to create such a critical instruction sequence with the standard library ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The mutex that is released in the `wait` operation *must* be the mutex that protects the shared state you are `wait`ing for.

Answer (score -1):

It's a good practice **not to assume**, that when you return from waiting on a condition variable, **the condition you waited for is satisfied**.

I would rather write this code as:

```
std::unique_lock<std::mutex> deque_lock(locks.deque_mutex_[st.id_]);
while(st.deque_.empty())
{
    deque_lock.unlock();
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> wait_lock(locks.restart_mutex_[st.id_]);
    locks.restart_condition_[st.id_].wait(wait_lock);   
    deque_lock.lock();
}
```

This code guarantees, that after the while your queue is not empty. [`std::condition_variable::wait`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/wait) can even take a predicate to simulate this king of behaviour (but, due to the queue locking, it cannot be used here).

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer and the advice, I will take that into account in my code. However, after the "deque_lock.unlock();" nothing guarantees that no concurrent thread will not add an object in the deque. Then the current thread will wait, whereas the deque is not empty. hence, I think that there is still a data race here.

Comment: It depends on what state you want to have in the queue. Condition variables are often used to wait while queue is not empty and having two elements doesn't bother you. As an afterthought I wonder, why not exclude access to queue and lock condition variable with one mutex, that is use only `locks.deque_mutex_[st.id]`. That would exclude your data race completely (I cannot say from these parts of code if this is a reasonable solution).